# Reloading page in IE 7 clears text from Input fields

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I have a web page,with a text input which a user will enter some text. There is a hidden input element on the page that stores the values submitted,so as a user keeps entering values , they will be appended to the hidden input element, I then use the value stored here to output all values entered to the user, see the code below

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">

function get_val(val)
{
    var name = val.input1.value;
    if(document.getElementById("input2").value != "")
    {
        var new_name = document.getElementById("input2").value;
        name = new_name.concat(" AND " +document.getElementById("input1").value);
        document.getElementById("input2").value = name
        alert(name);
              history.go(0); //this will be explained below
    }
    if(document.getElementById("input2").value == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("input2").value = name;
    }
}
</SCRIPT>


<h3>Enter word</h3>
<form id="frm1" name="frm1">
    <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" size="40" value="" />
    <input id="input2" name="input2" type="hidden" size="40" value=""/>
    <input id="button" name="button" type="button" value="get name" OnClick="get_val(this.form)"/>
</form>
```

Now note the history.go(0); line, I've put this in to demonstrate my problem. it works fine in most browsers, except **sometimes** in IE version 7.0.5730.1.3, when the page is reloaded, the hidden input element is cleared, causing undesirable results.

Does anyone know any reason why this occurs occasionally with Internet Explorer 7?

Comment: To me this would be desired functionality.  Reload = get the page from the server again (and the server will say they are empty fields.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why IE7 behaves that way...but I don't like the idea of relying on any browser to save form field's value consistently or reliably.

Store the values in a cookie instead of a hidden element.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more like a feature of browsers, you shouldn't depend on. Rather use cookies or session variables to keep the fields.